# Пробел между цифрами

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, тире, пробелы, цифры

Мы между цифрами ставим пробел, когда в виду имеем *от... до...*? Как правильно?

`Купи 10–20 / 10 – 20 помелов.` (Писалось бы так: *Купи десять – двадцать помелов.*)

Comment: Котик, минусую за помелов, жду исправления: https://kartaslov.ru/просклонять-существительное/помело

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• В орфографическом словаре:

[**поме́ло**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE) — *нескл.*, м. и с. (фрукт);
**помело́**, -а, мн. поме́лья, -ьев (веник, метла).

• У Розенталя ([§ 82. Соединительное тире](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/42.htm)):

> **1.** Тире ставится между двумя или несколькими словами для обозначения пределов:
> <...>
> в) количественных, например: *рукопись объемом восемь — десять авторских листов (то же цифрами: 8–10); 5–6-кратное превосходство.*
> В этих случаях тире заменяет по смыслу слова «от ... до».

• О фруктах:
*Купи **10–20** помело.* (Тире "короткое", без пробелов; *Alt0150*.)
*Купи десять — двадцать помело.* (Тире обычное, с пробелами.)

*...Шли мы втроем по деревне, а дети ели **плоды помело**, очень большие* (А. Кротов. В нагорья и джунгли Новой Гвинеи).

• О вениках:
*Купи **10–20** помельев.*
*Купи десять — двадцать помельев.*

> А ближе к двадцатому числу, когда отовсюду тянет запахом дыма, когда небо в сумерках оранжевое и пепельно-серое, вам начинает казаться, что уже никогда не наступит Хэлоуин — Канун Дня Всех святых — и вы не увидите летящих **помельев**, и не услышите мягкого хлопанья простыней на каждом углу.
> (Рэй Брэдбери. Что-то страшное грядёт)